# Laravel where_column1_and_column2 error?

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 4 PHP Framework when I write this method:

> where_email_and_password($email, $password)

show this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   '_email_and_password' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users`
>   where `_email_and_password` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 =>
>   'email@example.com', ))

See code and error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn85M.png

Comment: It looks like `where` is a keyword in Eloquent, so maybe change the function name to just `email_and_password`

Comment: @TimWithers does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are migrating from Laravel 3 where this is a valid method call. In Laravel 4, everything follows the camel case convention. I have not tested this but looking at the source code for the method that handles dynamic wheres, try `whereEmailAndPassword($email, $password)`

See the method here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L747

Hope this helps.

Comment: THANKS WILLIAM IT'S WORKED <3